# Empty histogram when data is in a small interval

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have some data in the interval of 1-x < data < 1+x where x is around 5*10^(-7).
Partial data: `[1.0000000478958904, 1.0000000478515068, 1.0000000480679452, 1.0000000477731508, 1.0000000479978082, 1.000000047790137, 1.0000000478526028, 1.0000000479145206, 1.000000047740274,...]`

I am trying to plot this data as a histogram with matplotlib and get an empty plot when raising the number of bins.
For example, when I define the number of bins to be 100, I get a single line histogram around 1, but when I set the bins to 1000 I get an empty histogram.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(data, 100)
plt.show()
```

I tried to use a log scale but obviously, it didn't work.
The length of the data is 5000 if that helps - tried to set it to the number of bins but I still get an empty plot.

How would I scale this data in order to plot it while best representing the real data?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `bins` parameter to set the specific bounds of each bin instead of just the number of bins. From the [Matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

*If bins is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the left edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin; in this case, bins may be unequally spaced.*

so, you can for example create bins based on the max and min values of your data:

```
import numpy as np

nr_bins = 10
bin_arr = np.linspace(min(data), max(data), nr_bins, endpoint=True)
```

and then:

```
ax.hist(data, bins=bin_arr)
```

Comment: Still gets me either a single line histogram or an empty plot

Comment: yeah, empty bins are still not displayed